# How to show remaining task effort in org-mode's column view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock

I use the column view to show my estimated effort for my tasks, and work. It is very useful to schedule the tasks of the day. But I would like to see the remaining effort of each task, i.e., (estimated effort) - (clocksum) instead of the estimated effort. Is it possible to add a column with the Remaining effort instead of the Estimated effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the following specifier `%(expression)` from the documentation of `org-agenda-prefix-format`.
the expression would calculate the difference between the clocksum and the effort estimate. Here's how you would write it:

```
%(org-minutes-to-clocksum-string (abs (- (org-clock-sum-current-item) (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (or (org-entry-get (point) \"Effort\") \"0:00\")))))
```

What's happening here is that we're getting the estimate effort of the task at `point` in `HH:MM` format and then converting it to minutes to perform the subtraction with the clocksum which is already in minutes. After that we apply the `abs` function to make sure we get a positive number of minutes. Finally, we convert the minutes to `HH:MM` format.

Here's an example on how you would use it in `org-agenda-prefix-format`:

```
(org-agenda-prefix-format "  %i %-15:c [%(org-minutes-to-clocksum-string (abs (- (org-clock-sum-current-item) (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (or (org-entry-get (point) \"Effort\") \"0:00\")))))] ")
```